# ImmutableArray how to use properly

Tags: c#, arrays, immutability, immutable-collections

I'm trying to create an array of constant values that CANNOT NEVER change. I try something like this....

```
public class ColItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }              // real header name in ENG/CHI
    public string HeaderKey { get; set; }           // header identifier
    public bool IsFrozen { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; } = true;
    public int DisplayIdx { get; set; }
}

public struct DatagridSettingDefault
{
    public static ImmutableArray<ColItem> DataGrid_MarketPriceTab = ImmutableArray.Create(new ColItem[] {
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "ORDER_ID", IsFrozen = true, DisplayIdx = 0 },
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "PRICE_RENAMEPROMPT", IsFrozen = false, DisplayIdx = 1 },
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "PRICETBL_TRADESTATENO", IsFrozen = false, DisplayIdx = 2 },
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "PRICETBL_BIDQTY", DisplayIdx = 3 },
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "PRICETBL_BID", DisplayIdx = 4 },
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "PRICETBL_ASK", DisplayIdx = 5 },
        new ColItem { HeaderKey = "PRICETBL_ASKQTY", DisplayIdx = 6 }
}
```

However, this array STILL gets changed from somewhere (another thread) of the code.
How can I make an array constant and absolutely cannot change through the lifetime of the program?
I just need to initialize this during compile time and no matter what reference or other thread change it, it should not change. But my my case, it keeps changing.

Such as, it gets changed if I do something like this later in the code, or through another thread...

```
HeaderKey = col.Header.ToString(),
Header = "whatever"
IsFrozen = col.IsFrozen,
IsVisible = true,
DisplayIdx = col.DisplayIndex
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: An immutable array is just that, an immutable array. However it doesn't protect you from shooting yourself in the foot with mutable reference types. Either use a readonly struct (not really recommended) an `Record`, or immutable class

Comment: how can i make it constant? i have tried ReadOnlyCollection and similar things, but nothing works.

Comment: Why not just use `IReadOnlyList<T>`?

Comment: The problem is your `DataGrid_MarketPriceTab` field is still mutable.

Comment: You can use read-only which does not change the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `ImmutableArray<T>`. Just do this:

- Change `DataGrid_MarketPriceTab` from a mutable field to a getter-only property.
- I recommend using `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead of `ImmutableArray<T>` because it's built-in to the .NET's BCL whereas `ImmutableArray<T>` adds a dependency on `System.Collections.Immutable`.
- Notice that the property is initialized inline as an `Array` (`ColItem[]`) but because the *only* reference to it is via `IReadOnlyList<T>` then the collection cannot be changed without using reflection.

  - Making it a `{ get; }`-only property means that consumers of your class cannot reassign the property value.
  - If you do need to use a field (instead of a property) then make it a `static readonly` field.

You also need to make `ColItem` immutable - that can be done by making all the member-properties `{ get; }` instead of `{ get; set; }` (and ensuring *their* types are also immutable):

Like so:

```
// This is an immutable type: properties can only be set in the constructor.
public class ColItem
{
    public ColItem(
        string headerName, string headerKey, int displayIdx,
        bool isFrozen = false, bool isVisible = true
    )
    {
        this.Header     = headerName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(headerName));
        this.HeaderKey  = headerKey ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(headerKey));
        this.IsFrozen   = isFrozen;
        this.IsVisible  = isVisible;
        this.DisplayIdx = displayIdx;
    }

    public string Header     { get; }
    public string HeaderKey  { get; }
    public bool   IsFrozen   { get; }
    public bool   IsVisible  { get; }
    public int    DisplayIdx { get; }
}

public struct DatagridSettingDefault // Why is this a struct and not a static class?
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<ColItem> DataGrid_MarketPriceTab { get; } = new[]
    {
        new ColItem( headerName: "Order Id", headerKey: "ORDER_ID", isFrozen: true, displayIdx: 0 ),
        new ColItem( headerName: "Price", headerKey: "PRICE_RENAMEPROMPT", IsFrozen:false, displayIdx:1 ),
        new ColItem( headerName: "Foo", headerKey: "PRICETBL_TRADESTATENO", IsFrozen:false, displayIdx:2 ),
        new ColItem( headerName: "Bar", headerKey: "PRICETBL_BIDQTY", displayIdx:3 ),
        new ColItem( headerName: "Baz", headerKey: "PRICETBL_BID", displayIdx:4 ),
        new ColItem( headerName: "Qux", headerKey: "PRICETBL_ASK", displayIdx:5 ),
        new ColItem( headerName: "Hmmm", headerKey: "PRICETBL_ASKQTY", displayIdx:6 )
    };
}
```

---

If all of that seems tedious to you, I agree! The good news is that [if you're using C# 9.0 or later (which requires .NET 5, unfortunately) you can use Immutable Record Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types), so the `class ColItem` class becomes `record ColItem`:

```
public record ColItem(
    string Header,
    string HeaderKey,
    bool   IsFrozen = false,
    bool   IsVisible = true,
    int    DisplayIdx
);
```

Comment: thanks, this seem to work, you saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ColItem` class immutable.  There are a few ways to this, but the most direct way is by removing the `set` keyword from your properties making them `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an immutable reference type, you can either make all the properties private setters. Or in C# 9 you could use init only properties, which can be constructed with object initializers

```
public string Header { get; init; }
```

Or you can take it one step further and create a `Record` which has several other advantages, such as *With-expressions*, *Value-based equality* and differ from struct with *Inheritance*

```
public record ColItem
{
   public string Header { get; init; } // real header name in ENG/CHI
   public string HeaderKey { get; init; } // header identifier
   public bool IsFrozen { get; init; } = false;
   public bool IsVisible { get; init; } = true;
   public int DisplayIdx { get; init; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
 var test = new DatagridSettingDefault();
 test.DataGrid_MarketPriceTab[0].HeaderKey = "asd";
```

Will generate the below compiler error

> CS8852    Init-only property or indexer 'ColItem.HeaderKey' can only be
> assigned in an object initializer, or on 'this' or 'base' in an
> instance constructor or an 'init' accessor.

Then all that is left is choose an immutable collection / collection interface

Comment: I'm generally opposed to `init`-properties because they enable consumers to violate a class' invariants that would normally be imposed by the constructor. `init`-properties only make sense for _optional_ data where every property's state is entirely independent from all other properties, which in-turn necessarily means `String` properties must be nullable (as `String?`) - which your `record ColItem` is not, which makes it unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make the `ColItem` class immutable:

```
public class ColItem
{
    public string HeaderKey { get; }
    public bool IsFrozen { get; }

    public ColItem(string headerKey, bool isFrozen = false)
    {
        HeaderKey = headerKey;
        IsFrozen = isFrozen;
    }
}
```

By declaring only the `get` accessor, a property becomes immutable everywhere except in the type's constructor. ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-a-lightweight-class-with-auto-implemented-properties))

In C# 9 there is also the option for `{ get; init; }` properties, that are mutable during initialization, and become immutable after that, as well as the new `record` types that are immutable by default.

And here is how you can make the static property `DatagridSettingDefault.DataGrid_MarketPriceTab` immutable, by marking it as [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly):

```
public class DatagridSettingDefault
{
    public static readonly ImmutableArray<ColItem> DataGrid_MarketPriceTab
        = ImmutableArray.Create(new ColItem[]
    {
        new ColItem ("ORDER_ID", true),
        new ColItem ("PRICE_RENAMEPROMPT", false),
        new ColItem ("PRICETBL_TRADESTATENO", false),
        new ColItem ("PRICETBL_BIDQTY"),
        new ColItem ("PRICETBL_BID"),
        new ColItem ("PRICETBL_ASK"),
        new ColItem ("PRICETBL_ASKQTY"),
    });
}
```